# Yahoo financial data in r with zoo

Tags: r, zoo

Hello i want to import a . csv file  in r, i have the following code :

```
fbmonthly<-read.zoo("E:\\R\\Stockforecast\\Data\\AAPLmonthly.csv",sep=",",header= TRUE, format = '%m/%Y', FUN=as.Date)
```

Although i have this error :

> Error in read.zoo("E:\R\Stockforecast\Data\AAPLmonthly.csv", sep = ",",  : 
>     index has bad entries at data rows: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62

my csv file looks like `01-03-13    0   0   0   0   0   0
01-04-13    63.128571   63.607143   55.014286   63.254284   47.519821   2740872400
01-05-13    63.494286   66.535713   59.842857   64.247147   48.265705   2361882600
01-06-13    64.389999   64.918571   55.552856   56.647144   44.609531   1754634000
01-07-13    57.527142   65.334282   57.317142   64.647141   50.909512   1634528700
01-08-13    65.10714    73.391426   64.751427   69.602859   54.812115   2014584600
01-09-13    70.442856   72.559998   63.888573   68.10714    56.215424   2157735300
01-10-13    68.349998   77.035713   68.325714   74.671425   61.633572   1959433000
01-11-13    74.860001   79.761429   73.197144   79.438568   65.568352   1306288900
01-12-13    79.714287   82.162857   76.971428   80.145714   68.953758   1764349300
01-01-14    79.382858   80.028572   70.507141   71.514282   61.527653   2191488600
01-02-14    71.80143    78.741432   71.328575   75.177139   64.679031   1470091700
01-03-14    74.774284   78.428574   74.687141   76.677139   68.836685   1250424700
01-04-14    76.822861   85.632858   73.047142   84.298569   75.678795   1608765200
01-05-14    84.571426   92.024284   82.904289   90.428574   81.181992   1433917100
01-06-14    90.565712   95.050003   88.928574   92.93   86.802559   1206934800
01-07-14    93.519997   99.440002   92.57   95.599998   89.296494   1035086000
01-08-14    94.900002   102.900002  93.279999   102.5   95.741524   937077000`

can you please help me?
Thanks

Comment: Umm.... where are the commas?

Comment: That is an obvious question but read.zoo inherits its default separator from read.file rather than from read.csv, so that's not the cause of the error. It also inherits its default for header and that would be an error, as well as the more glaring error with the format spec

Comment: Correction: inherits from `read.table`

Comment: I'm only nominating the question for reopening from a sense of "justice". I thought the question had enough information to support a valid answer. The lack of commas in the example is not sufficient for closure. I suppose if the questioner refrains from accepting one of the answers we can imagine that none of them are correct.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a "CSV" file. It's delimiter appears to be whitespace, which is what read.zoo would use by default. No header, also the default for read.zoo. Need to correct the date format:

```
read.zoo(text="01-03-13    0   0   0   0   0   0
 01-04-13    63.128571   63.607143   55.014286   63.254284   47.519821   2740872400", 
 format = '%m-%d-%y')
                 V2       V3       V4       V5       V6         V7
2013-01-03  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000          0
2013-01-04 63.12857 63.60714 55.01429 63.25428 47.51982 2740872400
```

Answer (score -1):

```
   fbmonthly<-read.zoo("E:\\R\\Stockforecast\\Data\\AAPLmonthly.csv",sep=",",header= TRUE, format = '%d-%m-%Y', FUN=as.Date)
```

If you have header and comma separated file it seems you have the date format wrong.

Comment: Wrong date format. Wrong sep. No header.

Comment: I think the Yahoo API went out of service almost 1 year ago.  I think you should use Quantmod for this kind of task.  

https://github.com/joshuaulrich/quantmod/blob/master/demo/chartSeries.R

https://www.r-bloggers.com/a-guide-on-r-quantmod-package-how-to-get-started/

Answer (score -1):

so you say to use `fbmonthly<-read.zoo("E:\\R\\Stockforecast\\Data\\AAPLmonthly.csv",sep=".",header= TRUE, format = '%m-%Y', FUN=as.yearmon)`

instead?

Comment: Wrong sep. No header.  Incorrectly used `format` and `FUN`.

Comment: Please do not use answers to ask questions.  Use comments.